# Hiring a graduate student for R&D research

Tags: colleagues, new-job, internship, collaboration, research

Recently I started working in a company as an intern. The things that I am working are for the future of the company and applications that I develop solves companies existing problems.

I am facing three types of people at work.

type 1. I noticed some of my colleagues wants to work on my project and they even come and tell me how to solve the problem. They sometimes even tell my manager that they had already suggested these ideas before I got hired. They even offer to do these project outside of the company(like finding random students on the internet and asking them to do the project for a low price)

type 2. this type shows themselves very interested in knowing and learning what I am doing. However, when I find interesting things and explain to them the things that I am doing, they just get intimidated and just want to be away from my work. (They might think that I would ask them to do part of my work; fake interest)

type3. they want to stick to the outdated technology and do not want really any update on the current systems. They always find a way to tell the new offered technology can not be mounted on the current system and can not communicate.

I am confused, what is the interpretation of those behaviors and what should be one's reaction to those type of things? Have you faced any of these people at work?

any advice would be appreciated as I am new to working.

Comment: Commented on this earlier... deleting & reposting loses people's effort.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I suggested that programmer post in this group as well as the Academia one. I didn't realise he would delete the post. Cross posting is usually acceptable especially if it is declared upfront.

Answer (score 5):

Some of your colleagues will see you as this:

> Type 4: people that believe that new technology X is extremely
>   important and should be integrated with all aspects of the business.
>   Typically new graduates or interns, these people have no understanding
>   of the flaws and limitations of X, the costs of implementing it, and
>   have very limited understanding of the business as a whole.

This is obviously not 100% accurate but you should pay attention because:

1. understanding how colleagues see you will help you to work with them
2. some of the description is true

Likewise, your descriptions/typing of your colleagues are not accurate. People are nuanced creatures and often highly knowledgeable. The more you treat them as such the better you will understand them.

This stuff can be tricky and no one gets it exactly right.

In general self awareness is a good starting point. Trying to think carefully about other people and what motivates their behaviour as individuals is another good line of attack (put yourself in their shoes - why do they act the way they act?). It is also a good idea to be generous. There are few truly worthless people out there and some of the daft-looking ones can turn out to be quite smart.

Comment: this is the whole idea of asking a question here" why do they act the way they act?" I want to know this.

Comment: @programmer ok, I can offer some hints but they may not be correct. People can adopt similar behaviours for wildly different reasons.

Comment: Type 1 - this sounds like someone who would have liked to complete a project similar to your own. Very often people can be pigeon-holed into doing a particular task. It is only natural for them to be a little envious of the fact that you get to work on exciting technology X (especially if they really did propose the commercial use of X but got rejected).

Comment: Type 2 - people are very often intimidated by something which appears complex. People tend not to want to talk about things which intimidate them. Bear in mind that even very smart people don't necessarily want an in-depth discussion about something complicated which they haven't been given time to understand properly. In general you want to try and keep conversations within the comfort zone of the participants (i.e. keep it within their field of expertise). This may mean that you can't talk meaningfully about aspects of your project with some people. Find something else to talk about instead.

Comment: Type 3 - this sounds very pragmatic. Adopting new systems costs a huge amount of time and resources. Huge. Even more huge than you are imagining. Sticking to pre-existing technology and techniques avoids a lot of risk, costs, and painful mishaps.... and is therefore very pragmatic. Some people take this pragmatism far too far but in general "we don't need or want this new thing" is a pretty reasonable opinion to have.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the real world, 3 types of people that **you have to learn** how to deal with, communicate with and work with.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, this seems too short for an answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I made an effort twice now, more than sufficient.

Comment: Oh, I see your comment on the Q. Understood.